# Convert only values from list of dictionary to list of list without changing order using Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dict from which I need to convert all the dict values into list of list without changing the order.

I used empty list and tried to append dict values using for loop but its not in order.

For example:

```
    result = [{'Project': 'ABC','Employee': 'MNK','Project': 'ABC','Project': 'ABC'}]
```

I want in below format:

```
    answer = [['ABC'],['MNK'],['ABC'],['ABC']]
```

I used below code:

```
    answer =[]
    for i,j in enumerate(result):
        answer .append(result[i].values())
```

What I got is

```
    answer = [['MNK'],['ABC'],['ABC'],['ABC']]
```

Expected answer is

```
    answer = [['ABC'],['MNK'],['ABC'],['ABC']]
```

Note: I am looking for code which gives expected answer, I checked other questions, none of them related to this. Right suggestions and codes are accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have duplicate keys? A dict cannot have dup keys!

Comment: To expand upon DirtyBit's comment: Your `result` data as illustrated is equivalent to `[{'Project': 'ABC', 'Employee': 'MNK'}]` – there's no way to get the result you want in Python.

Comment: It is not a dictionary to start with.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment with the new list:

Using `map()`:

```
result = [{'T_Project': 'ABC','T_Employee': 'MNK','T_Project1': 'ABC','T_Project2': 'ABC'}]

print(list(map(lambda x: x.values(), result)))
```

Using `list-comprehension`:

```
print(list(x.values() for x in result))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[dict_values(['ABC', 'MNK', 'ABC', 'ABC'])]
```

[pyFiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/90fc3cd4-3839-427a-aedf-b2ab6966c469/?i=true)

**EDIT**:

**Python 2.x**:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
d['T_Project'] = 'ABC'
d['T_Employee'] = 'MNK'
d['T_Project1'] = 'ABC'
d['T_Project2'] = 'ABC'

print(d)
print(list(d.values()))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
OrderedDict([('T_Project', 'ABC'), ('T_Employee', 'MNK'), ('T_Project1', 'ABC'), ('T_Project2', 'ABC')])
['ABC', 'MNK', 'ABC', 'ABC']
```

[pyFiddle 2.x](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/2ccde934-af49-4b81-874c-6a91f857c0c8/?i=true)

Comment: I got some thing like this [['ABC', 'ABC', 'MNK', 'ABC']]

Comment: @KarthikGowda I have a feeling you're on Python 2.x.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: @KarthikGowda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360509/does-dict-values-returns-in-an-ordered-sequence

Comment: @KarthikGowda provided a way out for Python 2.x in my edit.

Comment: Ok if I change result to just list ['T_Dept.ABC', 'T_EMP.NAME', 'T_PRO.ABC', 'T_Mastert.ABC'] and how to extract text which is after period in list values? example ['ABC','NAME','ABC','ABC']

Comment: @KarthikGowda That is a different question but still `print([x.split(".")[1] for x in r])` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you've written your question input dictionary wrong and I will assume it looks like this:

```
result = [
    {'Project': 'ABC'},
    {'Employee': 'MNK'},
    {'Project': 'ABC'},
    {'Project': 'ABC'}
]

x = [list(d.values()) for d in result]

print(x)
```

Which will yield what you want `[['ABC'], ['MNK'], ['ABC'], ['ABC']]`

Comment: You're altering the original list provided in the question.

Comment: @DirtyBit I'm pretty sure he wrote it wrong. forgot a few brackets, hence the assumption in my answer.